# Issues with GSP Grails 5.3, Loop issue and Unexpected Expression error

Tags: grails, gsp

I am running into a couple issues that I'm hitting a brick wall on and looking for other opinions on what is happening.

First issue is I am getting an Uncaught Syntax Error: expected expression got '}' from an onchange on a drop down.

```
<div id="questionResponse${bean?.id}ControlCroup" class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <g:hiddenField name="reviewQuestionResponse.${bean?.id}.id" value="${bean?.id}" />
    <g:select class="input-block-level" name="reviewQuestionResponse.${bean?.id}.response" from="${com.moo.qwr.enums.QuestionResponseType.values()}" value="${value}"
              onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'reviewQuestionResponse', action: 'update', id: "${bean?.id}",
                      params: '\'response=\' + this.value',
                      onSuccess: "jQuery(\"#reviewSaveNotice\").stop(true).fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut();jQuery('#questionResponse${bean?.id}ControlGroup').removeClass('error');updateQuestionScore(data);" +
                      remoteFunction(
                            controller: 'review', action: 'renderScore', id: "${bean.reviewSection.review.id}",
                            update: 'scoreTotal'
                      ) + ";" + remoteFunction( controller: 'review', action: 'renderSectionScore', id: "${bean.reviewSection.id}", update: "sectionScore${bean.reviewSection.id}"),
                      onFailure: "jQuery('#questionResponse${bean?.id}ControlGroup').addClass('error')"
              )}"
    />
</div>
```

This code was working in previous versions of grails but is now giving the error after moving to Grails 5.3.

My second issue is on loading of a form screen for editing and creating, one area is a cause of a lot of speed issues.   Create is only a few seconds, but on edit it is coming up to 8 - 10 minutes.  Previous version was seconds but still long.

```
                            <g:each status="fieldIdx" in="${reviewInstance.fields}" var="it">
                            <g:if test="${fieldIdx % 3 == 0}">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                            </g:if>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <g:render template="reviewFields/${ClassUtils.getShortNameAsProperty(it?.class)}/input" model="[reviewInstance: reviewInstance, reviewField : it]"/>
                            </div>
                            <g:if test="${fieldIdx % 3 == 2}">
                                </div>
                            </g:if>
                        </g:each>
```

When I throw a breakpoint on the g:each line, it comes to that point quickly, however when it tries to go to the next line, it is taking a long period of time.

The domain that review instance does have this inside it

```
List additionalRecipients = []
List managers = []
List reviewSections = []
List comments = []
SortedSet fields
ScoreSummary scoreSummary

static hasMany = [
    reviewSections : ReviewSection,
    fields : ReviewField,
    additionalRecipients: UserProfile,
    managers: UserProfile,
    comments : ReviewComment
]
```

Any insight is appreciated.   Thank you

Comment: Fixed the syntax error, needed to change the double quotes around reviewSaveNotice to single quotes.

Comment: How many items are in 'fields'?  Also, anecdotally, having a SortedSet rather than a Set in a domain object causes problems.  Sorting is expensive, and typically only needed in views.  Persisting that is possibly unnecessary, and may lead to a huge number of persistence events that you don't actually care about.

Comment: On my test it is only 2 at the moment.   Maximum amount would be 25.  Maybe it is the SortedSet causing the issue.

Comment: Changing to Set did not change the load time unfortunately.

Comment: It seems like the slowness is when it is trying to read in the in="${reviewInstance.fields}".   I tried to load up a line with "${reviewInstance.fields[0].class}" and that also took a long time to load up.   When I hit the loop, I have values in the fields that is two objects.

Comment: I would turn up hibernate/SQL logging and see what queries are being generated.

Comment: That gave me my answer.  For some reason it is looking through every user instead of just the ones that are selected.  That I can fix.  Thank you